# Comparing a Float with an Int in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, floating-point, integer, reportbuilder3.0

I have a field where I'm using `LEN()` to calculate the string length and then I'm comparing this to a value generated by `AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT,LEN(some_field)))`.

The point of the comparison is to do **THIS** if the first value is less than the second and **THAT** when the value is greater than.

My question is this: when comparing 2 values of the data types above, at what decimal place does the system stop using further decimal places for the floating point value and then decide to round it?

As an example, the comparison is `10` compared to `9.5`. So it will pick one of the options (doesn't matter which). But then what about `10` compared to `9.99999999999999999`? Will the system decide that `9.99999999999999999` is actually `10`, thus ruining the point of the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts required to answer this.

> when comparing 2 values of the data types above, at what decimal place does the system stop using further decimal places for the floating point value and then decide to round it?

The *limit* at which the rounding or truncation of a floating point number occurs is based on the system's precision for that data type. For a [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773(v=sql.110).aspx) it is up to 15 digits.

Using your code as an example, if you had 11 strings with a total length of 29, `AVG` will return: 2.63636363636364 (a non-terminating, repeating number) terminated at the 15th digit.

If you were to try and represent 9.99999999999999999 as a float, it would round to 10.

> I'm using LEN() to calculate the string length and then I'm comparing this to a value generated by AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT,LEN(some_field))).
>
> But then what about 10 compared to 9.99999999999999999? Will the system decide that 9.99999999999999999 is actually 10, thus ruining the point of the comparison?

Firstly, keep in mind that `AVG()` return type is based on the parameter's data type (refer to "Return Types" section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177677.aspx), and because you are explicitly converting `LEN(some_field)` value to a float, your `AVG()` result will always be a float value. If you require greater precision and scale such as 9.99999999999999999, consider converting the parameter to a `decimal` instead.

Secondly, because `LEN()` returns a value of type `int`, and `AVG()` returns a value that may not be an `int` as mentioned above, your comparison's between values of two different data types and [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) comes into play.